# Rendering JS after CSS transition in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, angular-ng-if

So I have a button, when clicked the `onGoToAbout` function is called. This function sets an elements height to 0 and also sets the `desk` boolean variable to `false`. This variable is connected to an elements `*ngIf`.

My problem is that the `*ngIf` is executed before my CSS transition takes place. I'm thinking I need a delay of sorts but can't figure  out how to implement that!

Below is my code. Using jQuery is not an option.

```html
onGoToAbout(event) {
 document.getElementById("slideshow").style.height = "0vh";
        this.desk = false;
    }
```

Comment: Which css transition are you talking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply delay `this.desk = false` with a timeout :

```
setTimeout( () => { this.desk = false }, 500 )
```

This way, your CSS transition will perform, then, after 500ms, the variable will be set to false.

Also, of course jQuery is not an option in an Angular app :) `document.getElementById` shouldn't even be used, as it's not angular-y, but let's say that if it's done only to perform a CSS transition, it's okay.

Comment: what would be your suggestion to use other than `document.getElementById` ?

Comment: well, use the Angular way with [ngStyle](https://alligator.io/angular/style-binding-ngstyle-angular/)